# Silverlight client-side report generation using mvmm

Tags: silverlight, reporting, client-side

we are developing a Silverlight 4.0 (C#, .NET 3.5) application using the MVVM design pattern.
Is it possible to create reports on the client-side with the existing ViewModels or does it have to be done on the server-side? On server-side we only have models and we don't want to copy our business logic to the server. I know ServiceHost is not available in Silverlight and we can't use a WindowsService. Non-free solutions are also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done but to what extent you need is slightly up to you. Pete Brown posted an example on creating a [simplistic report writer](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/05/09/creating-a-simple-report-writer-in-silverlight-4) which may suffice based on your needs and is free; allowing you to build on top of the example as needed.

If you moved up to .NET 4 you could leverage the [Silverlight Reporting](http://silverlightreporting.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex.

telerik also offers a [reporting package](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx); however it is not free and requires the full .NET runtime for generation. Don't confuse the .NET runtime as an assumption that it must be server side generation as that is not the case.

Comment: The telerik reporting package only supports server-side report generation. We want to generate the reports on the client-side. I'll have a look into the mentioned Silverlight Reporting, but further suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Thomas It does not require server side generation but it does require the full .NET runtime; answer edited.

Comment: Aaron, Telerik says it cannot support client-side report processing. Please see http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/can-report-processing-be-done-in-client-side-silverlight-app.aspx.

Comment: @Abdul The .NET FW is needed which is why _client side_ in a strict Silverlight environment won't work. If the client possess the entire .NET FW it is possible.